# IOS Filling TableViewController with array [__NSArrayI] 0 out of bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Hi !

I want to fill up a tableview with a simple array with simple custom cells.
It seems I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not experienced enough in objective-c yet to figure it out myself. I could use some help ;)

This is my controller implementation :

```
@interface tongilKupGradenTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation tongilKupGradenTableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *arrayBanden;
    NSMutableArray *arrayOmschrijvingen;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayBanden = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Witte band",@"Gele band",@"Groene band", @"Blauwe band", @"Rode band", @"Zwarte band",nil];
    arrayOmschrijvingen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Weinig to geen voorkennis in Taekwondo.", @"Introductie in de basistechnieken.", @"Basistechnieken onder de knie.", @"Technieken uitbreiden en verbeteren.", @"Technieken meesteren en perfectioneren.", @"Meester in de kunst.", nil];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tongilKupTableViewCell";
    tongilKupTableViewCell *cell = (tongilKupTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tongilKupTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.lblBandTitle.text = [arrayBanden objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblBandOmschrijving.text = [arrayOmschrijvingen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
reason: '*** [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ef1012 0x13d3e7e 0x1ea6b44 0x757ce4 0x547ee3 0x3cdf13 0x36240c 0x3cda7b 0x3d2919 0x3d29cf 0x3bb1bb 0x3cbb4b 0x3682dd 0x13e76b0 0x7042fc0 0x703733c 0x7037150 0x6fb50bc 0x6fb6227 0x6fb68e2 0x1eb9afe 0x1eb9a3d 0x1e977c2 0x1e96f44 0x1e96e1b 0x21297e3 0x2129668 0x317ffc 0x21fd 0x2125 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Maybe relevant, when debugging with breakpoints I see that the code passes the numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSections twice, I'm wondering if this could be the cause?

Comment: Check that the array you've named `nib` is not empty.

Comment: I don't know why my question is downvoted. I don't really care but an explanation would be nice...

Comment: @RobbieVercammen: First of all you should set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C exceptions" to see where the exception exactly occurs. Then show the stack backtrace.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, Robbie. I upvoted you to try balance it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `viewDidLoad` add the following code to load the nib you want to use for your table cells:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"tongilKupTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tongilKupTableViewCell"];
```

Then inside of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` all you need to do is:

```
tongilKupTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tongilKupTableViewCell"];
cell.lblBandTitle.text = [arrayBanden objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblBandOmschrijving.text = [arrayOmschrijvingen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Just be sure that you have your nib properly named and that you have set the reuse identifier properly on the cell inside of the nib.

Comment: With a breakpoint on tongilKupTableViewCell $cell = ..., I can see that the cell properly assigned and that all fields are visible in the cell variable. After stepping over (step by step) it hits the return cell line twice, but It's pointer is set to 0x000... this time.
This proves that the nib is properly named and that the identifier is also correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: If I continue running after this I get a SIGABRT message in the main.m and get the same exception as posted in my question.

Comment: Make sure that the cell looks good after stepping over the line where it is assigned.  You'll also want to make sure that the right class for the cell is set inside of your nib (in addition to the reuse identifier).

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense to me. The variable Cell does contain all the fields it should and they are assignable as you can see. Even with a global breakpoint, I still get the same exception at the same location (main.m with SIGABRT message)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing man here in this code?

```
 NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tongilKupTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
 cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

You loaded an nib!!! And from the nib you tried to access it like an array.

**Instead of loading a nib you need to create a new `cell`**.

You should do something like this, style you can choose according to need.

```
if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"eventCell"];
}
```

***Edit 2:***

Also if your nib contains some predefined cell, then you can directly use the string you created, why again hardcoding? :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tongilKupTableViewCell";
....
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: That's perfectly legal. There's a chance that the nib name is incorrect or for some reason the returned array is `nil`.

Comment: Huh, that was actually quite stupid of me... I'll give it a try and get back to you

Comment: Well, If I try your approach it says that I have incompatible pointer types to my custom cell (tongilKupTableViewCell) which contains a few labels, so I'm guessing UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle is incorrect?

Comment: StackOverflow Admin, please make mandatory to downvote, atleast OP and readers can know whats wrong here in the answer.

Comment: @RobbieVercammen; do a sanity... is your NNSBundle mainbundle with specified name, returns you a valid Array?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Well, it's not null and it contains 1 object, so I don't see why not. Do you need more info?

Comment: check its type, is it array and what kind of object it stores, a view/cell etc...

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your two arrays as properties in your interface :

```
@interface tongilKupGradenTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayBanden;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOmschrijvingen;
@end
```

And then synthesize them :

```
@implementation tongilKupGradenTableViewController

@synthesize arrayBanden;
@synthesize arrayOmschrijvingen;

...
```

Comment: Instance variables are also be default strong. So even if using properties is recommended, I cannot see why this explains or helps with the runtime exception.